# Prevent Routing/Page Load when Data Has Been Modified

Tags: routes, kendo-ui, single-page-application

I am using Kendo UI for a LoB SPA and I have a requirement to present the user with a warning when the model has had changes so that the user can save/discard their work.

I am not sure what the best way to integrate this into the router would be and to also deal with navigation away from the app (not just navigation to another route).

It seems like this is a common feature (you find it on all the StackExchange sites as well as FB) so I suspect their might be a built in method to perform this that I am not aware of.